# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save() on seed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to create seeders to my models using seed and factory. My models have relationship one to many. When I run

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ChildTableSeeder
```

I get the following error:

```
In Builder.php line 2461:

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

Independently of the error the data seed is added to the target table.

My table's structure is like follow:

```
parents
        - parentId
        - name
        - value

    childs
        - childId
        - parentId
        - views
        - count
```

And my models:

```
//Parent.php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Api;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parent extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'parentId';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}


//Child.php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Api;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Child extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'childId';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Api\Parent', 'parentId', 'parentId');
    }
}
```

Also see the Seed code

```
//ParentTableSeeder
factory(App\Models\Api\Child::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
        $u->parents()->save(factory(App\Models\Api\Parent::class)->make());
});
```

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong? or How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `associate()` function insted of `save()`

Also `parents()` relationshiop's definition is wrong

```
public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Api\Parent', 'parentId', 'childId');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `associate` method instead of `save` when creating the relationship:

```
$p = factory(App\Models\Api\Parent::class)->create():
$u->parents()->associate($p);
$u->save();
```